# Problems with binding forms in Java controller

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am  working on playframework and I have problem with scala forms when i apply the .get() methode to the form to create object i got all the object attributes are null.

here is my code:

```
import play.data.*;
import static play.data.Form.*;

public static Result save() {
Form<myobj> boundForm = cardForm.bindFromRequest();

    if(boundForm.hasErrors()) {
        flash("error", "Please correct the form below.");
        return badRequest(page1.render(boundForm));

    }
    myobj temp= boundForm.get();
     temp.save();
    .
    .
    .
  }
```

the problem is all the attributes in "temp" are null although when i add breakpoint in the intellij-idea and see the values inside the form i see that it has data

Comment: Could you please add the form mapping code and the test request you are sending?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the data binding stopped working at some point and all attributes was null.
The `form.getData()` gave back a map where all data was present, but the form's object was empty (all attribute null).
I suspected there is an error with the reflection, so deleted the target directory and compiled the classes again with the play framework. And now it works again.

I think it is a compatibility issue with the idea compiler versus play compiler, but I hadn't investigated the problem further.